# How to Abstract Types and inheritence in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I know most of you already know of the animal-cow-grass-food problem

-which states that you have a code like below, that has a type constraint on **Cow** (which inherits **Animal** ) to only eat **SuitableFood** (which inherits **Food** )

Below is the SCALA representation of the same

---

```
class Food
class Grass extends Food
class Cookies extends Food
class Fish extends Food

abstract class Animal {
  type SuitableFood <: Food
  def eat(food: SuitableFood)
}

class Cow extends Animal {
  type SuitableFood = Grass
  override def eat(food: SuitableFood) = {}
}

val bessy: Animal = new Cow
bessy eat new Fish
bessy eat new Cookies
```

---

I was wondering if similar is possible in KOTLIN or JAVA ?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing. Your code does not compile in Scala even if I add `bessy eat new Grass` and remove the last two lines, because the type of `bessy` is `Animal` at compile-time, so the compiler does not know whether `bessy` can eat `Grass` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to achieve. Restriction for `Cow` to eat only `Grass` ?
I think this can be done through generic types.

```
abstract class Food

open class Grass : Food()
class GreenGrass : Grass()
class Fish : Food()

abstract class Animal<T : Food> {

    fun eat(food: T) { ... }
}

class Cow : Animal<Grass>()
class Bear : Animal<Fish>()

class Test {

    fun test() {
        val cow = Cow()
        cow.eat(Grass())        // ok
        cow.eat(GreenGrass())   // ok
        cow.eat(Fish())         // not ok

        val bear = Bear()
        bear.eat(Fish())        // ok
        bear.eat(Grass())       // not ok
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to know if  `// not OK` can be disallowed in this data structure?? Generics is something I know. Type binding to generics at the time of definition is something Im interested in. Is that possible in Kotlin ?